# Can I create a proto jar for scalaVersion 2.11/2.12 and use it within the same sbt under different sub-project?

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers

I have a set of .proto files (protobuf) which I generate java from using scalapb.  I also have in the same sbt 2 sub-projects, one is scalaVersion 2.11 compatible (can't upgrade it to 2.12 due to missing packages) and the other one is scala 2.12.

I created a sub-project to hold my proto, and by default 2.12 is used and my 2.12 sub-project can use it, but my 2.11 can't.

I set the crossScalaVersions to 2.11/2.12, I compiled my project with both, which passed, but then even then I was unable to get the 2.11 sub-project to find that code.

I am "wondering" if that is something supported, or if there is a track I could use a single location to hold my .proto yet have my 2 sub-projects using the same sbt file use those.

```
lazy val scala212 = "2.12.13"
lazy val scala211 = "2.11.12"
lazy val supportedScalaVersion = List(scala212, scala211)

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := scala212

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(proto, subproject1, subproject2)
  .settigns(
    crossScalaVersions := Nil,
    publish / skip := true
    )

lazy val proto = project
  .settings(
    crossScalaVersions := supportedScalaVersions,
    name := "proto",
    libraryDependencies += "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % com.trueaccord.scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf",
    PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
      scalapb.gen(grpc = false) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "protobuf"
    )
    )

lazy val subproject1 = project
  .dependsOn(proto)

lazy val subproject2 = project
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := scala211
  )
  .dependsOn(proto)
```

So, from the above, if I do `sbt "+ proto"` I can compile both versions.  If I do `sbt subproject1/compile` it works too.  Using `sbt subproject2/compile` fails indicating that it cannot find the 2.11:proto jar file.

Either, I would like the above somehow to work nicely, or any other trick that I could generate the code from the same proto location but within subproject1/subproject2 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the sbt-projectmatrix plugin:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-projectmatrix
The idea is to have separate sbt subprojects for the different Scala versions, so you can simply reference the relevant subproject when calling `dependsOn`.

I think this plugin is going to end up in sbt some day as it's a much better solution in general than the current built-in stateful cross compilation support, and it's developed by Eugene Yokota, who is also an sbt developer.